# Burninate [common-practices]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[common-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-practices) has no wiki summary, is only tagged on 34 questions, and seems to be tagged on questions that are primarily opinion based. Of course, not all of these questions necessitate opinion-based answers, they're just poorly defined. In general though, it looks like a variant of [best practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/231078).

Comment: This *exists*? What happened to the great burnination/blacklisting task? Where are our saviors!

Comment: Handled a handful or two. Have fun with the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Processing...

Done.